# What to detect in url's HTML as thumbnail?

Tags: php, html, url, thumbnails

I am creating a PHP thumbnail app for links. I get the HTML content of the url, I repair it and I traverse through it to find anything that would suit as a thumbnail for that URL.

First option is of course cheching for the OG(OpenGraph) - let's put OG aside, because searching for `og:image` in `<meta>` parameters `name` or `property` is an easy one and the process doesnt relate with this question.

However what if there is no OG source - I guess I would check content of all classes and id's for what?

What strings whould I search for? (logo, thumb, ... ?) and in what priority order?

Or is there any NON-external PHP API providing this functionality ?

## EDIT

**Important**: the question has been misunderstood - the question is NOT about how to traverse through DOM tree or how to find the `<img>` The question is about what to consider when searching for it - what class names/ids and so on... and in what priority order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly how facebook do it, maybe try looking at the facebook docs or googling, but here's something you could do to get you started...

First of all, have a fallback check for the old style:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/myimage.jpg"/>
```

If that fails, then you need to select an appropriate image. You could get really fancy and do google-esc scraping which trys to put things into context such as looking for images inside the main content frame only (dictated by checking other website urls and identifying the common layout template). But to start with you could try,

1. Get all image tags and parse out the src attribute
2. Purge any sources which aren't unique (might indicate icons like social icons)
3. Fetch all images to a temp directory
4. Purge any images whose size is not indicative of a featured image (i.e anything smaller than 300px maybe? You'd have to play with it i guess).
5. Purge any images whose aspect size is wildly outside that of an expected featured image

Optionally before step 3, you could try removing any images which are within close proximity of another image in the source code, which could identify things like image navigation menus.

Anything more than that would probably require a contextual understanding of the webpage being scraped (which is probably what facebook do). An image followed by several paragraphs for example could indicate a featured article image.

On top of all of that, if you made it a factory class where you can plugin additional parsers for specific sites. You could try to build and plugin more specific parsers for common website layouts, such as wordpress and other CMS's, where 90% of the time, you could probably reasonably expect to be able to identify the main content area of the website at very least to narrow your search (if not the exact image of an article if the template isn't too customised)

Comment: @jave.web: In that case: uniqueness, size, aspect ratio, relation and context are just a few. I apologise for providing a more informative answer. Next time i notice you asking a question, i'll ensure i keep it as brief as possible let you work out how to implement it yourself... geez

Comment: Take no offense please :) , still I was asking about the context analyzing - how to detect its priority order just by analyzing the attributes of the image itself or its parent's attributes. Do we understand each other  now  ? :)

Comment: Yes, you want a simple answer to a very complex question. Unfortunately, there is no answer anyone could give you that is as simple as you want, and being reliable. Anything after the OG tags you have tried and the fallback link i placed above, will get complex to do properly.

Comment: Well, I agree I may missread a part of your answer, but my question was "What **strings** whould I search for?" and the question name contains "in urls' **HTML**" - I will give you a vote up, because your answer is at least related to the question and answers the rhetorical "guess?" question part :)

Comment: Note I want to avoid any extra external-image downloading, So as for image-size sorting: I could check the html attributes of "<img>" but what if there are none... Then I would have to download the image first to get its size - am I right?

Comment: PLEASE READ: You got me thinking about the thing that class names may really vary... I am now considering even accepting your anwswer - but could you please do one thing ? :) - edit your answer so it would contain the comment on the string-in-class-search uncertainty?

Comment: @jave.web What comment on string in class uncertainty? You already know that class names and id's are not a reliable way to get a featured image... i can't really see how i can expand on that

Comment: I would just be nice if you put the "class names and id's are not a reliable way to get a featured image.." into your answer - I know it already, but its for others :) I will accept your answer, but please, could you do that ? :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You can do your work like below by searching different type of tags(img, og tags, etc...);

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url =''; // To be crawled
$images = array();
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('img') as $img){ // img is an option. 
    if (!empty($img->getAttribute('src')))
    array_push($images, $img->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

**EDIT:** I have gave how to implement to crawl html page and find `img` like tags. However, main problem here is how to find images. I have given an option `img` only. And I said that you can use another tags also

Comment: The question is NOT how to find the image but WHAT TO CONSIDER when looking for it .

Comment: I have put comment for "img". You can use other options like <link  rel="icon, shortcut icon" href="...". But my answer does not worth downvote. I have gave you the clue

Comment: No you completely misunderstood my question your answer is not related with my question , sorry I just had to downvote - even I don like to do that... If you are willing to check again what I am actually asking - and please check EDIT - and you will edit your answer correctly - I will remove the downvote or even give you an upvote ... :) ...  I even wrote in the original question "... <meta> parameters name or property is an easy one and  the process doesnt relate with this question."

Comment: I really know how to traverse and search through the DOM tree. Just a tip for you - always repair the HTML with tidy first - what if the html is invalid ... :)

Comment: If html is invalid, html_dom_parser cannot get html to convert. You need to use regular expressions in order to parse as string. You dont need to tidy for parse

Comment: Ok at least now it seems you have understood what I was asking about :)